# Running command after for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have three commands that I want to run sequentially, one of them FOR, which need to go in the middle.

I can implement the functionality as a batch file, as shown below:

```
pushd \\server\share
FOR /R %%f in (".") DO copy /y "ALL\sample.pdf" %%f
rmdir /q /s ALL
```

However, I need to write this in a single line. I tried to do following:

```
pushd \\server\share && FOR /R %%f in (".") DO (copy /y "ALL\sample.pdf" %%f) && rmdir /q /s ALL
```

However, this results in the `&& rmdir /q /s ALL` to be executed by the FOR loop as well. What I need is a way to delimit the FOR loop when placing it in a single command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use parentheses correctly to make your intent clear:

```
pushd \\server\share & (FOR /R %%f in (".") DO copy /y "ALL\sample.pdf" %%f) & rmdir /q /s ALL
```